# Cannot create new directory on ftp server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

I am trying to create a directory on my FTP server. I had already created `ContractorDoc` directory on server and want to create new directory `NewDirectory` in it.

```
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://abc.xyz.com/ContractorDoc/NewDirectory");

            // Step 2 - Configure the connection request
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("uname", "passsword");
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = false;

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;

            // Step 3 - Call GetResponse() method to actually attempt to create the directory
            FtpWebResponse makeDirectoryResponse = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            String status = ((FtpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusDescription;
        }
```

I get an exception:

```
550 Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that the "NewDirectory" doesn't exist?

Comment: have you tried to access your ftp from a third-part software (or from windows file explorer) and observe if the directory exists or not?  you may already have created it in one of your prev. executions

Answer (score 0):

I think he's got to make sure there folder.
There is no error in the code. Maybe there's a problem with the server.

```
    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://abc.xyz.com/ContractorDoc");
    ftpRequest.Credentials =new NetworkCredential("uname","password");
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    List<string> directories = new List<string>();

    string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
        directories.Add(line);
        line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    }

    streamReader.Close();
```